# Complex line integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, line-integrals, analytic-functions

Suppose we have an analytic function then Why complex integral of that function does not depend on the path of integration?

Comment: Read about Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: Because the integral around a closed loop is zero.  This follows from Green's theorem in the plane.  Look in any book on complex variables.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the complex integral depends on the path of integration !

Example: $D= \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}, f(z)=1/z$ and $c(t)=e^{it}$ with $t \in [0, 2m \pi i]$ for some $m \in \mathbb N$.

Then we have $\int_c f(z) dz = 2m \pi i$.